# How do I add a field to a user in Pimcore?

Tags: pimcore, pimcore-v5

I want to add a field for all my users as I do with Data Object Classes.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can add a new field as per your requirement to the user class which will be reflected to the whole user data object class.